# Invoking function stored in a struct using Rust

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm new to Rust, and I'm writing a basic command line input parser as a learning exercise. Commands entered on the command line are evaluated using the `Cmd` struct which contains the name of the command and a function to call when invoked. Though the code works, I find the use of the `get_invocation` function to be a little weird.

```
pub struct Cmd<T: FnMut()> {
    name: String,
    invocation: T,
}

impl<T: FnMut()> Cmd<T> {
    pub fn new(name: &str, invocation: T) -> Cmd<T> {
        Cmd {
            name: String::from(name),
            invocation,
        }
    }

    pub fn invoke(self) {
        self.get_invocation()();
    }

    fn get_invocation(self) -> T {
        self.invocation
    }
}
```

I am aware that I could use `(self.invocation)()` to directly call my struct function in `invoke()`, but that would involve setting the invoke `self` parameter to mutable, which would require me to make each instance of `Cmd` mutable if I wish to use the `invoke()` function. This is something I would like to avoid as, conceptually, nothing in the struct is being mutated. Is there a less odd / more idiomatic way to deal with stored function invocation in Rust, while still maintaining immutability? I also would appreciate any other pointers/tips on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct applications of mutability in Rust:

1. Bindings (variables) can be mutable or immutable.
2. Borrows (references) can be mutable or immutable.

Here, you're not using any borrows, so we're only concerned with bindings.

Note that *values* are not intrinsically mutable or immutable. Therefore, when you move a value from one binding to another, you can change the mutability. The methods `invoke` and `get_invocation` take ownership of the `Cmd`, therefore they can decide to declare `self` as mutable, even if the original value is not declared as mutable. For example, this is valid:

```
impl<T: FnMut()> Cmd<T> {
    pub fn invoke(mut self) {
        (self.invocation)();
    }
}

fn help() {
    println!("not implemented yet :)");
}

fn main() {
    let cmd = Cmd::new("help", help);
    cmd.invoke();
}
```

If you were to take `self` by mutable reference, rather than by value, then the original variable would indeed need to be declared as mutable. You could not invoke the function with only an immutable reference, because `FnMut` closures can't be invoked from an immutable borrow. If that's a problem, switch to `Fn` instead.

```
impl<T: FnMut()> Cmd<T> {
    pub fn new(name: &str, invocation: T) -> Cmd<T> {
        Cmd {
            name: String::from(name),
            invocation,
        }
    }

    pub fn invoke(&mut self) {
        (self.invocation)();
    }

    fn get_invocation(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.invocation
    }
}

fn help() {
    println!("not implemented yet :)");
}

fn main() {
    let mut cmd = Cmd::new("help", help);
    cmd.invoke();
}
```